# How can I use multiple pm.expect in one pm.test in postman tests

Tags: javascript, postman

I want to check if request has a string then response has to contain this string in postman. I write a test like this but it doesn't work for me. I'm not sure I can use multiple pm.expect in one test with condition. My code is

```
pm.test("test",function(){
var hasA = data.hasOwnProperty('A');
var hasB = data.hasOwnProperty('B');
if(hasA === true){
        pm.expect(response.A).to.eql(data.A);      
}
if(hasB === true){
        pm.expect(response.B).to.eql(data.B);      
}});
```

Request can contain A and B both so I cannot use if..else statement. When I run this test if hasA flag true then code doesnt go into for second if even hasB option is true. How can I handle this problem.Can anyone help?

Comment: how do you i doesn't goto next one?

Comment: I dont understand what you exactly mean but I understand "how do you say i doesn't goto next one?" from your question. I added a log inside each if and second if's log doesn't written to the console when both boolean are true. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: So in that case the expect condition passes or fails ? Expect is a hard assertion so it won't goto next line if one except fails

Comment: I want to check B even A fails. How can I do that then? Is there any  way to do that? Maybe its unnecessary but I want to know is there any way.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expect is hard assertion so if one fails then it won't goto next one so you can use any of the below approach:

**try if conditions like:**

```
pm.test("test", function () {

    var hasA = data.hasOwnProperty('A');
    var hasB = data.hasOwnProperty('B');
    var hasBoth = hasA && hasB
    if (hasBoth) {
        pm.expect([response.A, response.B]).to.eql([data.A, data.B]);
    } else if (hasA) {
        pm.expect(response.A).to.eql(data.A);
    } else if (hasB){
        pm.expect(response.B).to.eql(data.B);
    }
});
```

or

try catch like :

```
pm.test("test", function () {

    var hasA = data.hasOwnProperty('A');
    var hasB = data.hasOwnProperty('B');
    let error = {};
    try {
        if (hasA) {
            pm.expect(response.A).to.eql(data.A);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        error.A = e
    }
    try {
        if (hasB) {
            pm.expect(response.A).to.eql(data.A);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        error.B = e
    }

    if(Object.keys(error).length){
        pm.expect.fail(JSON.stringify(error))
    }
});
```